# How do I get the JSON response from httpModule.get?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I can't figure out how to get the JSON string from the HttpModule's `get()` function. I am using this API endpoint as my target: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1

As you can see this endpoint returns a JSON string. I can't figure out how to get this JSON string within my Angular code. I keep getting things like Observable or some other garbage.

```
export class LicenseService {

  users: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getUsers(): void {
    const data = this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1').subscribe(res => this.users = JSON.stringify(res));
    console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

I have also tried this, which doesn't work.

```
public getUsers(): void {
    const data = this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1');

    data.subscribe({
      next(response) {
        this.users = response;
        },
      error(err) { console.error('Error: ' + err); },
      complete() { console.log('Completed'); }
    });

    console.log(this.users);
  }
```

I thought I was supposed to use .subscribe to do this but every time I try and use the next function within subscribe I don't get what I want back.

All I want to do is be able to access the JSON that is returned by the endpoint, how do I do this.

Comment: JSONs are decoded automatically by Angular if the server returns correct headers

Comment: Can you show what do you get in the two console.log statements?

Comment: When you do `console.log(this.users);` outside the subscribe it runs before `this.users = JSON.stringify(res)`. Do this inside subscribe `.subscribe(res => {console.log(this.users); this.users = JSON.stringify(res)});` Observable's are awesome when used witht the async pipe or you could use resolvers to get the data before the component is constructed.

Comment: With respect, [the official documentation is very clear on the matter.](https://angular.io/guide/http) You also seem like you could use an [introduction to asynchronous programming concepts.](https://dev.to/siwalikm/async-programming-basics-every-js-developer-should-know-in-2018-a9c)

Comment: Example using async pipe https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8eujks

Answer (score 4):

I already made another answer but here is a better working one using rxjs as it should be used.

Service: `license.service.ts`

```
export class LicenseService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1').pipe(map(res=> res.data));
  }
}
```

Component: `license.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-license',
  templateUrl: './license.component.html',
})
export class LicenseComponent {

  constructor(private licenseService: LicenseService) { }
  users$ = this.licenseService.getUsers();

}
```

Template: `license.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
  {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
</div>
```

Comment: @Jake12342134 if this answer fits your need, could you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is close.

This code does not work because you are mixing asynchronous with synchronous. `console.log(this.users)` gets executed before the call to the backend is completed.

Try this:

```
public getUsers(): void {
    this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1').subscribe(res => {
        this.users = res;
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

[EDIT]:

If you want to return the data, you would have to do something someone else suggested - transform this to async function.

But here, you probably should not do that. The thing with RxJS is that once you go Rx, you should stay Rx. You should try to work on observables using the `observable.pipe()` and various operators like `map()`, `filter()`, `every()`, `count()` etc. (more can be found in documentation - [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api).

At the end of the chain of different methods working on these observables you should have single call to the `subscribe`. This way, you will be working with observbables almost as you would work with synchronous code and won't need to worry about things like that from your question.

Comment: Okay but how can I access the `data` array that's held inside the response from the API?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the async function and toPromise method to transform your observable to a promise.

```
export class LicenseService {

  users: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async getUsers() {
    this.users = await this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1').toPromise();
    console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

Comment: While that's possible (so IMHO not worth a downvote :) it's still _extremely unidiomatic._ It will lead OP to architect _synchronously_ from the Service up to the Component, and then things will start breaking when other async things happen. Better to implement observable the way it was intended. The whole point of RxJS is to build _reactively._

Comment: I totally agree with you but the thing is that the person who asked the question doesn't seem to understand the rxjs concept very well yet. Here I give him an answer that works now.
The best way would be to use an async pipe in the template.

Comment: Matt, part of my comment was directed at OP and future readers ;) No worries.

Comment: You're right, I wrote another better full answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You very clearly aren't understanding how asynchronous methods interact with the rest of your synchronous code. I'll break down your first code for you.

```js
//call the http service and use it to perform an HTTP GET.
//This is an asynchrounous call, meaning it out does not lock the rest of the application.
//The HTTP GET call starts, then the rest of your code runs.
const data = this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1')

//At this point, the HTTP GET has started, but since it is async, we do not wait for it to finish.
//So we log users. Users is CURRENTLY undefined (since our call hasn't finished yet.
console.log(this.users);

//After some (indeterminate) quantity of time, our HTTP GET finishes it's call.
//Now that it has finished its call, we perform the callback within the subscription.
//The subscription is an observable because it emits an event when it is finished.
//In our callback, we set the value of users.
.subscribe(res => this.users = JSON.stringify(res));
```

As others have mentioned, there are a few ways to solve the problem. You can either use async/await (which is an ES8 feature) to delay the console log of users until your HTTP GET finishes it's call. This is the same code that @Mateusz provided. This is **not** the *correct* way to handle the situation, but async/await is a JS feature that you should understand.

```
async getUsers() {
   this.users = await this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1').toPromise();
   console.log(this.users);
}
```

Alternatively, you can restructure your code to utilize the user data while within the callback of the observable. This is probably the better way to handle the situation. You will need to redesign your code so that it can handle the result of the async call as it comes down from the server. Simply putting your log into the callback solves the current problem, but you'll need to think about other scenarios, especially how you are using the user data.

```
this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1').subscribe(res => {
   this.users = JSON.stringify(res);
   console.log(this.users);
});
```

Comment: Okay this is all well and good, but how do I even make use of the JSON that is being returned by the API call. If I do `res => { return res } ` then I get some weird object that is not a JSON object. I understand how async code works, what I don't understand is how to actually get access to the JSON being returned by the API. All I want to do is get the JSON and then deserialise it into some kind of object so it can be used.

Comment: You do use the json. You use it in the subscription callback. Since its an async function, you have to wait for it to finish to do stuff with its result. That's the point of the `.subscribe`

Comment: So how do I get the my JSON out of the callback and into synchronous variable I can use elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get data from the **LicenseService** to a component. While **toPromise()** is an option. You can also use **map** operator.
I have created an example. Here is the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-api-call

Comment: Okay but logging it to the console is useless, how can I return it to another method so I can actually make use of the returned json?

Comment: @Jake12342134 Stick `<pre>{{users | json}}</pre>` into the html template to see this directly or just use `this.users` in your other methods